# How do I declare an immutable variable (value) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, immutability

In Scala I can write (and it will mean exactly the same thing it means in C#)

```
var v = 1;
v = 2;
```

but can't write (well, of course I can write but can't compile actually though the syntax is correct)

```
val v = 1;
v = 2;
```

Semicolons are not necessary but can be voluntarily used in Scala so I've decided to include them to let the code correspond C# more closely. `val` means an immutable value, a kind of a variable that can be only assigned once but, unlikely to c# `const`s can be initialized with a result of a run-time expression, unlikely to C# `readonly` fields can be introduced at any place in the code where a `var` variable can and, unlikely to C# immutable types is immune to a reference replacement, not just modification of the referenced object.

I enjoy the way C# introduces more and more functional coding candies in every new version of the language but miss this (arguably the most simple and the most essential)  one heavily. In the majority of the cases I only assign values to my variables once so re-assignment is usually something that is not meant to happen which means a thing that is not expected and can cause a bug this way. Might I, perhaps, just be unaware of such a feature? I don't mind such a declaration looking a little bit clumsy (some F# imports perhaps, whatever they might look like in C# code).

**UPDATE:** As it seems there indeed is no such a feature a by now (March 2017, C# language version 7.0) and as suggested by others I have submitted an [issue at the C# language design GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/304).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you can't - at least at the time of C#6 - with one notable exception mentioned below. Maybe something will change in future versions of C#. There were plans for "record types" for C# 7, it could open some way when paired with anonymous inline objects. However, I actually don't know what gets exactly added in C#7.

The only normal support for anything like that is at class member scope:

```
class Foo
{
    public readonly int shoeSize; // readonly field
    public int ShoeSize { get { .. } } // readonly property
    public int ToeSize { get; } = 5; // readonly property with initializer
    // ..etc
}
```

with read-only field being settable only during object member initialization or in constructor, and getters - well, should be more or less obvious.

At the scope of normal code, any '**variable**' (as opposed to 'member' above, or 'constants' you mentioned) you create is **(almost) always** writable, and assignment semantics will **always** differ depending on the kind (struct/class) of the variable's type.

EDIT: I've found one! Your note about clumsy syntax got me an idea. Actually, the **foreach iterator variable** is guarded against assignments by the compiler, so you can use it with Enumerable.Repeat to quickly open a foreach scope that will iterate just once..

```
static void Main()
{
    foreach(int x in Enumerable.Repeat(5/*value for X*/, 1/*single run*/))
    {
        x=4;   // <- compile time error!
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

EDIT2: another option, nicer, [tuple literal that is said to be added in C#7](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/tuples.md)

```
public static void Main()
{
        var pair1 = (42, "hello");
        System.Console.Write(Method(pair1).message);

        var pair2 = (code: 43, message: "world");
        System.Console.Write(pair2.message);
}
```

fields/properties of a Tuple are not writable, hence such tuple-literal will be quite handy, except for the 'pair2' extra identifier to write (and .. some cost of creating and disposing a tuple object)

**However, I actually don't know** if they are mutable or not. They are called "tuples", so I immediately think of "Tuple<>" whose properties are readonly, but then, [in this old article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/)

> Tuples are value types, and their elements are simply public, mutable fields.

Now, I don't (yet) have VS2017 installed.. It will take some time, maybe someone else will be able to check that sooner than me.

Comment: Version 7 is already out, it's what VS2017 uses.

Comment: @DavidG: thanks! I thought it's still in beta phase, seems it's out now, I'll check the release notes and update the answer

Comment: FYI there's nothing for immutable types added.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Nice hack (with `foreach`)! A way too clumsy for real life though. But I already doubt something reasonable actually exists.

Comment: @Ivan: I checked C#7 docs and updated by answer - tuple literal to the rescue!

Comment: I just wonder why won't they introduce Scala-fashioned immutable values. That's so easy (seemingly), even the `val` keyword seems vacant. And I believe this alone could increase general C# code reliability a way enough to notice.

Comment: @Ivan Go request it on the official repo then! https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Well, tuples seem more viable in this context, thanks!

Comment: @DavidG Thanks, I didn't knew there is a GitHub repo for C# itself, I've only noticed .Net Core stuff... I'll file the issue if it's not there already.

Comment: @Ivan: sorry :( I take it back https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/ - "Tuples are value types, and their elements are simply public, mutable fields." I hate when they reuse words.. Tuple<> is immutable. I assumed it will be the same here.

Comment: @Ivan That's probably the best place to ask, the meeting notes are there to read too, it can be rather interesting stuff. You might also want to take a look at this too https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/

Comment: @DavidG Thanks, I didn't knew there is a GitHub repo for C# itself, I've only noticed .Net Core stuff there... I'll file the issue if it's not there already, I'd even implement it myself but I'm a little bit afraid of trying to building all the stuff so far and somewhat discouraged by believing Visual Studio to be even harder to configure to accept new syntax than the compiler.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Ok, thanks, interesting idea anyway.

Comment: @Ivan Well I might shy away from implementing it, the devs in the C# team are on another plane of existance to us mere mortals! Anyway, [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/records.md) might be the proposal that works for you.

Comment: @DavidG The records proposal you've linked to seems a way far from a perfect implementation of the feature I've described but looks very cool too, there have been many times I needed something like these records ending up "inventing square wheels" to build something alike. Thank you very much for the link, feels a rather cool place to me already!

Comment: You may consider migrating this answer to existing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656918/variable-that-cant-be-modified which already provided `using` and `foreach` suggestions (also not sample code). C#7 is not there yet.

Comment: @DavidG can you do me another favour and explain how to vote the records feature proposal up? I could never find the upvote button there on GitHub (not the first button I had hard time looking for there).

Comment: @Ivan There is no upvote button on GitHub (apart from upvoting comments in issues)

Comment: I've submitted the issue: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/304